# Summation Sigma in Excel without VBA

Tags: excel

How can I do sigma calculation in Excel? I have:
[image]

, where Infinity is N (data starting from F5:F105)

How would I go about summing this?
Thanks.

Comment: Show sample data then expected output. You may need combination of few formulas to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, for example F5 = 10, F6 = 11, F7 = 12, ..., F105 = 110. So it's a arithmetic progression from 10 to 110

Comment: Then try this formula to F5 cell. `=SEQUENCE((110-10)+1,,10)` Sequence function is only available to Excel-365.

Comment: `=10+ROW(1:1)-1` to F5 cell and drag down till need for older version of excel.

Comment: As far as I anderstand it's a formula for creation sequence. I already have sequence and I want to calculate Sigma, but I haven't know any tools to do it.

Comment: You get overflow as k gets up towards 100 but I wonder if Stirling's approximation could help to simplify the formula for large n? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Probably not worth it as value gets vanishingly small for k>50.